# weird ! and space character while sending mail

Tags: php

So here is my situation : On a godaddy server, I've got a php script which sends periodically html emails (a kind of newsletters). And for a reason I can't explain, in some of the emails I send (always at the same exact spot), a ! character appear, along with an unusual space. Here are some example :

- "I am ! so certa in" instead of "I am so certain"
- "that anger ! at them" instead of "that anger at them"
- "to be childre! n during" instead of "to be children during"

Some more details regarding the script's mechanics : it reads the content email from .html files (converted from a .doc file - I know that's a wierd idea, and the html code generated is shitty, the formatting aim to resolve this issue), does some formatting, and sends it with the appropriate headers. What I did try to diagnose the issue :

- Tried to view the email with different software (from my gmail account, my old Windows live mail account and outlook). It's all the same.
- Tried to change the charset of the email (from utf-8 to ISO-8859-1).
- Made sure there was not any rogue character by using the html_entity_decode function.
- Checked if the file on the server didn't get deformed for some random reason - and it's note.

So any idea about this?

Comment: In the .html files themselves (the source), any of that weirdness present?

Comment: Have you examined one of the HTML files in question to see if the problem is resultant from the conversion from msword format?

Comment: @webbiedave and @Tom Dignan : Yup I did, and no, the problem isn't in the conversion... Though I only checked with gedit... I'll try to see what another file editor could give me.

Comment: have you checked that the linebreaks are appropriate for the system? Windows linebreaks on a *nix system can do weird things.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread75331.html

Comment: So yeah, I checked with notepad++ and everything is okay. @eykanal Yeah well in fact I replaced every linebreak (PHP_EOL) with nothing, since it created some issues at some point. Either way the .html file are created under ubuntu.

Comment: @John Rasch Nice find, sounds very much like my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check how many characters in from the start of the line they appear. You may well find the same number. This is where the line is being artificially broken. The solution is to just make shorter lines. With HTML-based emails, this is not a problem, as html does ignore line breaks in preference to the markup.